# How to infer type of a dynamically instantiated class without using annotations?

Tags: php, oop, php-7

I have a dynamic config where I've defined supported classes for usage:

```
'registeredRequestParameters' => [
    SearchParameter::class,
    ReturnsParameter::class,
    OrderByParameter::class,
    RelationsParameter::class
],
```

All of those classes extend an abstract class `AbstractParameter`.

Now when I am registering those in the package I'm developing, I am doing this:

```
foreach ($this->requestParameters as $parameter) {
    /**
     * @var AbstractParameter $instance
     */
    $instance = new $parameter($this->request, $this->builder, $this->configModel);
    $instance->appendQuery();
}
```

And this is working fine, however I need to say that `$instance` is actually an `AbstractParameter` because otherwise my IDE won't pick up that the method is from that class.

Is there a way to do this without annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using type **annotations**. That's what they are there for.

But I agree that proper **type hinting** is better and more robust.

But for that you cannot use not use dynamic instantiation. Use an abstract factory instead. This will make the code clearer, more flexible, and more explicit.

```
abstract class ParameterFactory {
    
    public static parameter($type, $request, $builder, $configModel) : AbstractParameter
    {
        
        switch ($type) {
            case SearchParameter::class:
                return new SearchParameter($request, $builder, $configModel);
            case ReturnsParameter::class:
                return new ReturnsParameter($request, $builder, $configModel);
            case OrderByParameter::class:
                return new OrderByParameter($request, $builder, $configModel);
            case RelationsParameter::class:
                return new OrderByParameter($request, $builder, $configModel);
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Class $type not supported by factory");
            
    }
}
```

Then you would do:

```
foreach ($this->requestParameters as $parameter) {  
    $instance = ParameterFactory::parameter(parameter, $this->request, $this->builder, $this->configModel);
    $instance->appendQuery();
}
```

As an aside, I would create a `ParameterInterface` and type-hint for that instead of an abstract class.